# Send email when Appwrite database gets update

Tags: javascript, react-native, appwrite

How to trigger notification on Appwrite when a record is added to my database?
The same function exists in Firebase, but in the paied plan .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please check this and update your question

Answer (score 1):

Appwrite doesn't include a notification service but you can make use of [Firebase Cloud Messagaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for to send your push notifications.

As for how to trigger the notification, the best way is to create an [Appwrite Function](https://appwrite.io/docs/functions) that triggers on document create. The function can use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send the push notification.